# Почему остался призыв помочь Монике, если пришли к соглашению?

Tags: обсуждение, stackexchange, кризис-2019

Почему у многих участников сообщества в названии имени есть призыв помочь Монике, если пришли к соглашению ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Похожий вопрос недавно на MSE задавали: [Checking in with ".*Monica.*" users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341412/260198). Там есть ответы и от наших участников. К примеру, от [меня](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341426/260198) или [Атари](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341524/260198).

Лично я оставил аву и ник, т.к. факт того, что компания и Моника пришли к соглашению, не говорит ни о чём. Проблема никуда не исчезла, кредит доверия подорван. Лично я верну назад ник, когда:

- Монику восстановят в должности модератора.
- Компания принесёт публичные извинения (а не просто [безликую отписку от юристов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340906/260198)).

Comment: Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica♦  спасибо не знал что задавали такой вопрос да и не узнал бы я почти не знаю английский язык

Answer (score 1):

Я лично считаю, что раз Моника приняла извинения компании SE Inc., то значит она согласна на компромисс.
Перевод моего ответа с MSE([Checking in with ".*Monica.*" users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341412/260198)):

> Я рад юридическому соглашению. Я рад, что Моника достучалась до
>   компании SE и заставила их переосмыслить то, что они сделали. И если
>   Моника приняла их извинения, значит, все кончено.
>
> *НО*
>
> Я **Ver Nick says Reinstate Monica**(*Ver Nick говорит восстановить Монику*). И я буду **Ver Nick said Reinstate Monica** (*Ver Nick говорил восстановить Монику*).
>
> Я хочу всегда напоминать SE об их ошибке и заставлять их помнить, что
>   может случиться (снова), если они будут действовать ненадлежащим
>   образом.

Comment: Компромиссы не всегда нравятся принимающим его сторонам, иногда это - вынужденная мера ;)

Comment: Извинения отдельно, компромиссы отдельно